# Trippe Product Integration, Fourier Series

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I am trying to calculate the coefficients of a fourier series of the function $e^{-|x|}cosx$. Since the function is even when I calculate $B_n$ I go from 0 to pi

$$B_n=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0 ^{\pi}e^{-x}cosx\cdot cos(nx) dx $$

Now I get to my issue, how can this be evaluated? Intergration by parts will not do anything and I cant see how to simplify it.

Comment: \begin{align}
\cos(x) \cos(nx) &= \frac{1}{2} \cos(x) \cos(nx) + \frac{1}{2} \sin(x) \sin(nx) + \frac{1}{2} \cos(x) \cos(nx) - \frac{1}{2} \sin(x) \sin(nx) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \cos((1-n)x) + \cos((1+n)x) \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \cos((n-1)x) + \cos((n+1)x) \right] \\
\end{align} then use integration by parts.

Comment: ... or just use $\cos z=(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2$.